# the int is not converting to a char for some reason

Tags: c

```
int myatoi(const char* string) {
int i;
i = 0;
while(*string) {
    i = (i << 3) + (i<<1) + (*string -'0');
    string++;
}
return i;
}

int main() {
int i = myatoi("10101");
printf("%d\n",i);
char a = (char)(((int)'0')+i);
printf("%c\n",a);


return 0;
}
```

my output turns out to be 
10101

�

how to fix this

should I parse int by int to convert into a char because we can use any c built in functions that can help us convert

Comment: If you're trying to be sneaky with `(i << 3) + (i<<1)` you're not. It's not going to be anymore efficient than `10*i`.

Comment: And exactly what are you trying to do? `10101` is not going to fit into a `char`.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: i want a 5 digit number into string of char so i should i make a char array?

Comment: Supposedly, the extended ascii character you should be getting from this is the Yen sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect to have happen?

Your code correctly converts the string `"10101"` into the integer `10101`, and prints it.  That looks fine.  You then compute `10101+(int)'0'` which is probably 10149 (in ascii or unicode, `(int)'0'` is 48).  Converting that to a `char` probably gives you 165 (or perhaps -91) which probably doesn't correspond to a printable character on your system, so you get a blank/garbage/missing character.

All is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

in case you only need a 5 digit number into string of char you can use this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int myatoi(char* string) {
int i;
i = 0;
while(*string) {
    i = (i << 3) + (i<<1) + (*string -'0');
    string++;
}
return i;
}


char *strrev(char *str) {
    char *p1, *p2;
    if (!str || !*str)
        return str;
    for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2) {
        *p1 ^= *p2;
        *p2 ^= *p1;
        *p1 ^= *p2;
    }
    return str;
}


char *itoa(int n, char *s, int b) {
    static char digits[] = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int i=0, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)
        n = -n;
    do {
        s[i++] = digits[n % b];
    } while ((n /= b) > 0);
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    return strrev(s);
}


int main() {
char buffer[5];
int i = myatoi("10101");

printf("%d\n",i);
itoa(i, buffer, 10);
printf("%s\n",buffer);


return 0;
}
```

source of the 2 functions I have used : itoa and strrev
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/11049/convert-int-to-string#

Answer (score 0):

A bit reworked and simplified variant:

```
unsigned int myatoi(const char* string)
{
  unsigned int i = 0;
  while(*string) i = (i << 3) + (i << 1) + *string++ - 0x30;
  return i;
}

int main()
{
  unsigned int i = myatoi("12133");
  printf("%u\n",i);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "trick"

```
printf("%c", '0'+5);
```

for getting the output `5` only works for (decimal) digits, i.e. 0-9. `printf("%c", '0'+10)` gives the output `:`. Why?

`printf("%c",..)` is for printing a single character. Each character has a numerical code (see [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/)). 65 is the ASCII code for `A`, so `printf("%c", 65)` gives this letter. `printf("%c", 48)` gives the character `0`. The C language allows to write `'0'` instead of `48`, so you do not have to remember the ASCII code. The C compiler translates any character  between `''` or `""` to its corresponding ASCII code. So the above code line is the same as

```
printf("%c", 48+5);
```

For converting an int into its string representation you can do it in C like this:

```
char repr[12]; // a 32-bit int has at most 10 digits; 
               // +1 for possible sign; +1 for closing 0-character ("null termination")
sprintf(repr, "%d", 10101); // prints the number into a string
itoa(10101, repr, 10); // does the same thing
printf("%s", repr); // prints the string representing the number
printf("%d", 10101); // does the same thing directly
```